# Add click function to standard controls of HTML 5 player

Tags: html5-video

I have a video with a custom play-button.

```
                    <div class="play_btn" ></div>
                    <video class="video">
                    <source src="myvideo.mov" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

With the following script I change the background of the button on play/pause

```
    $('.play_btn').click(function(e) {
    if ($('.video').get(0).paused){ 
        $('.video').get(0).play();
        $('.play_btn').css({'background':'none'});
    }
    else {
        $('.video:visible').get(0).pause();
        $('.play_btn').css({'background':'url(play.jpg)'});
    }
});
```

This works well so far. 
My problem is now, the HTML5 player has his own controls. And if I click on the play button there, my image does not change. I don't know how to give the standard control a click event.

I also tried to do something like: If video is playing/paused then change background, but that didn't work out.

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: From your question it seems you are using a video player framework. Are you? Which one?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than showing/hiding your play button in your click handler logic use the HTML5 media events. This way if something else plays/pauses the video your buttons will still react.

```
// in click handler simply play/pause the video
$('.play_btn').click(function(e) {
    if ($('.video').get(0).paused){ 
        $('.video').get(0).play();
    }
    else {
        $('.video:visible').get(0).pause();
    }
});

//on the video playing hide the play button
$('.video').get(0).bind('play', function(e){
    $('.play_btn').css({'background':'none'});
});

//on the video pausing show the play button
$('.video').get(0).bind('pause', function(e){
    $('.play_btn').css({'background':'url(play.jpg)'});
});
```

You should really be using an ID to reference your video tag as this would be faster and make your code a little simpler.

```
// in click handler simply play/pause the video
$('.play_btn').click(function(e) {
    if ($('#myVideo').paused){ 
        $('#myVideo').play();
    }
    else {
        $('#myVideo').pause();
    }
});

//on the video playing hide the play button
$('#myVideo').bind('play', function(e){
    $('.play_btn').css({'background':'none'});
});

//on the video pausing show the play button
$('#myVideo').bind('pause', function(e){
    $('.play_btn').css({'background':'url(play.jpg)'});
});
```